# PHP - Issue with Stripe API Create Card

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm not doing very well implementing the Stripe API for some reason. I have been working with creating customers and charges fine, but when I tried to add a new card to an existing customer I just cannot get it to work.

Here is the basic implementation from the API (simple enough) but it keeps providing errors:

```
$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($stripe_customer_id);
$customer->sources->create(array("card" => $token));
```

https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card

Error Log:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Stripe_InvalidRequestError' with message 'Missing required param: source' in / ... /scripts/stripe/stripe_library/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php:142
Stack trace: 
0 / ... /scripts/stripe/stripe_library/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php(254): Stripe_ApiRequestor->handleApiError('{\n  "error": {\n...', 400, Array) 
1 / ... /scripts/stripe/stripe_library/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php(104): Stripe_ApiRequestor->_interpretResponse('{\n  "error": {\n...', 400)
2 / ... /scripts/stripe/stripe_library/lib/Stripe/List.php(19): Stripe_ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/customers/c...', Array)
3 / ... /join/update-card-stripe.php(34): Stripe_List->create(Array)
4 {main} thrown in / ... /scripts/stripe/stripe_library/lib/Stripe/ApiRequestor.php on line 142
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `Missing required param: source`, might give you something to go on..

Answer (score 1):

I think stripes example documentation is out of date or incorrect.  Looking at the docs under "Definition" it should be:

```
$customer->sources->create(array("source" => $token));
```

Under "Example request" it does indeed have it exactly as you are doing it, but looking at the arguments documented to the left, it should actually be "source" not "card"

https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#create_card

Comment: Thanks. But I just tried swapping it out and I still get the same error.

`$customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($user_data["stripe_customer_id"]);`
`$customer->sources->create(array("source" => $token));`

Comment: How are you going about getting the card data.  Is it created with stripe.js? Or are you passing all of the card data from your own form to the backend?  I suspect the problem isn't with the API call but rather what you are passing

Comment: You're right. I was using a custom form to try it. When I used the basic embedded form it works fine. I will investigate that and see if I can correct the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I added a new card to the existing customer using the following code:

```
$customer_stripe_data = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve('customer stripe id');

$createdCard = $customer_stripe_data->sources->create(array("source" => $this->input->post('stripe_token')));

$customer_stripe_data->save();
```

I got the `$this->input->post('stripe_token')` by including stripe js file in my html file.

Answer (score 0):

I've created by customer and attempted to register the card, using the source token

```
// create a new customer if our current user doesn't have one
$stripe_customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
        'source' => $token,
        'description' => $displayname,
        'metadata' => array('BHAA_ID'=>$bhaa_id),
        'email' => $email
    )
);
$stripe_customer_id=$stripe_customer->id;
update_user_meta( $bhaa_id, 'stripe_customer_id', $stripe_customer_id );
error_log('$stripe_customer_id '.$stripe_customer_id);

// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29393338/php-issue-with-stripe-api-create-card
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve($stripe_customer_id);
$card = $customer->sources->create(array("source" => $token));
error_log('card '.$card->id);
```

but i get the same error

```
[16-Dec-2015 18:54:12 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'Missing required param: source.' in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/events-manager-pro-stripe-token-gateway-master/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php:103 from API request 'req_7Xq54M2AlKDijE'
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/events-manager-pro-stripe-token-gateway-master/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php(217): Stripe\ApiRequestor->handleApiError('{?  "error": {?...', 400, Array, Array)
#1 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/events-manager-pro-stripe-token-gateway-master/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php(60): Stripe\ApiRequestor->_interpretResponse('{?  "error": {?...', 400, Array)
#2 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/events-manager-pro-stripe-token-gateway-master/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiResource.php(108): Stripe\ApiRequestor->request('post', '/v1/customers/c...', Array, Array)
#3 /var/www/wp-content/plugins/events-manager-pro-stripe-token-gateway-master/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiResource.php(99): Stripe\Ap in /var/www/wp-content/plugins/events-manager-pro-stripe-token-gateway-master/vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/ApiRequestor.php on line 103
```

I suspect the issue may be in the Stripe PHP API

Comment: Saying you have the same problem should not be posted in the answer section, please post a new question or use the comment sections for things like that.